# Raggedbottom before Headings

Tags: vertical-alignment, scrbook

I'm using the scrbook class, which uses flushbottom paragraphs by default.

Usually this is OK, as a book looks better when the bottom part of the pages are aligned. But when a new section starts, a huge amount of space is inserted in the previous page to flush the bottom of the page.

Example:

```
\documentclass[draft=true,fontsize=10pt,pagesize,paper=148mm:215mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter 1}

  \section{Section 1}

  \blindtext[1]

  \blindtext[4]

  \blindtext[1]

  \blindtext[2]

  \section{Section 2}

  \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use `\flushbottom` paragraphs by default, but `\raggedbottom` on pages preceding a new section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an individual section that causes problems, you could issue `\clearpage` before that section.  Otherwise one could try something like the plain TeX `\filbreak` macro.  The following will push the section heading to the next page if there is less than `3cm` left, and makes the previous page essentially raggedbottom, closing up so that there is at most `3cm` gap at the bottom of the page.

Here section 2 causes a new page:

[image: Before section 2]

[image: Section 2]

But section 3 is placed as usual:

[image: Section 3]

```
\documentclass[draft=true,fontsize=10pt,pagesize,paper=148mm:215mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newskip\mfilskip
\mfilskip=0pt plus 3cm\relax
\newcommand{\mfilbreak}{\vspace{\mfilskip}\penalty -200%
  \ifdim\lastskip<\mfilskip\vspace{-\lastskip}\else\vspace{-\mfilskip}\fi}
\pretocmd{\section}{\mfilbreak}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[4]

\blindtext[1]

\blindtext[2]

\section{Section 2}

\blindtext[4]

\section{Section 3}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DaniloBargen Thanks for pointing this out.  I have now (further) updated the code so this is no longer a problem.

Comment: tex.stackexchange is incredible :) Thanks a lot, Andrew.