# Subsection on new page if it doesnt fit

Tags: page-breaking

I have many subsections in my document. Each subsection is quite short (each subsection consists of five to ten lines). I want to have more than one subsection on each page but I don't want a subsection to be splitted over two pages. If a subsection doesn't fit on the remaining of a page I want it to be placed on the next page.

Is there a page layout which does a `\newpage` automatically when a subsection doesn't fit on the page?

Comment: Unfortunately, a `subsection` 'environment' is not a floating environment, but perhaps, it is possible to use the `float` package to define a new floating environment which acts as `subsection`, starting at new pages if needed, but this would also mean, that due to some reasons, say `subsection 1.1` could appear after `subsection 1.2`, which is probably not desired by you? It is in my opinion also not a feature connected with a particular page layout.

Comment: What about sections? Should they start in a new page?

Comment: A very partial solution, reducing the number of manual page breaks could be loading the `titlesec` package with the `nobottomtitles` option and syaing, e.g.: `\renewcommand{\bottomtitlespace}{5\baselineskip}`.  This would ensure  the shortest subsections couldn't be split. It would also be the case for sections.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152278/15925 help?

Answer (score 5):

I can't see such a style without section starting off in a new page. So here it is: we add `\clearpage` before all `\section` commands (after the first) and `\filbreak` before every `\subsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto{\section}{\clearpageafterfirst}
\preto{\subsection}{\filbreak}
\newcommand{\clearpageafterfirst}{%
  \gdef\clearpageafterfirst{\clearpage}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate dummy text for the MWE

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{author}
\maketitle

\section{A section} 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[1-2] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[8]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[9]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[10]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[11]

\section{B section}

\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[12]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[13]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[14]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[15]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[16]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[17]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[18]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[19]
\subsection{A long subsection}\lipsum[20-25]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[26]

\end{document}
```

If a subsection is longer than one page it will go to the next one without problems.

[image]

If you don't want that sections start on a new page it's slightly more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{aftersection}
\preto{\section}{\filbreak\global\toggletrue{aftersection}}
\preto{\subsection}{\iftoggle{aftersection}{\global\togglefalse{aftersection}}{\filbreak}}
\newcommand{\clearpageafterfirst}{%
  \gdef\clearpageafterfirst{\clearpage}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate dummy text for the MWE

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{author}
\maketitle

\section{A section} 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[1-2] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[8]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[9]

\section{B section}

\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[12]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[13]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[14]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[15]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[16]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[17]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[18]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[19]
\subsection{A long subsection}\lipsum[20-25]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[26]

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can enjoy reading about `\filbreak` in the TeXbook. See also [suppress pagebreaks in titletoc's titlecontents* blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56100/suppress-pagebreaks-in-titletocs-titlecontents-blocks/56102#56102)

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be  fix a variable spacing above the subsections with the `titlesec` package and left to LaTeX to do the best. In the MWE below is from `2.8ex` to `9ex` so LaTeX use a spacing of `3ex` when possible, otherwise is enlarged more or less, or even reduced in a barely perceptible extent, in order to obtain the best results.

You can combine this also with a variable paragraph skips to obtain a better result (as showeed in the MWE).

Note that paragragh/subsection splitting is almost avoided completely if you apply huge spacing ranges, but I do not think it's a good idea for more than 3 or 4 lines. You should play with these values in your final text to find a reasonable range and allow paragraph breaks in some cases (i.e, check that there are not ugly page breaks after a few lines in your pages). See also [How do I prevent widow/orphan lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines).

In any case, remember that you can always force large unbreakable blocks using a `minipage` environment or a `\parblock` command (manually for some final tuning or in a macro for general use, as in the MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate dummy text for the MWE

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{3ex plus 9ex minus .2ex}{1ex plus .0ex minus .0ex}

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 3ex minus 0ex}

\newcommand\monoliticsubsec[2]{
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\subsection{#1}#2
\end{minipage}} 

\begin{document}
\section{A section} 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[1-2] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4] 
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[4]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[5]
\monoliticsubsec{A unbreakable section}{\lipsum[1-3]}
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[8]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[9]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[10]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[11]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[12]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[13]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[14]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[15]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[16]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[17]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[18]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[19]
\subsection{A long subsection}\lipsum[20-25]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fairly consistent (maximum) subsection length, then a rudimentary approach would be to use the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace) to insert a page break if there is less than (say) `12\baselineskip` available on the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace

\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\needspace{12\baselineskip}\oldsubsection}

\newcommand{\lorem}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
\newcommand{\dummytext}{\lorem{} \lorem{} \lorem{} \lorem{} \lorem}

\begin{document}
\section{A section} 
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext
\section{Another section}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext
\subsection{A subsection}\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext\dummytext

\end{document}
```

`12\baselineskip` is *approximately* 10 regular lines of paragraph text plus a `\subsection` heading.